# Vagrant is failing to unpackage Ubuntu Bionic box

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I've tried the following on two different hosts (MacOS and Windows 10):

```
vagrant init ubuntu/bionic64
vagrant up
```

However on both machines I get the same error:

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'bionic' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///Users/user/Downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and that enough disk space
is available and then try again.
The output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

x box.ovf
x Vagrantfile
x metadata.json
x ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg.mf
x ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg.vmdk: Truncated tar archive
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

So far, I've tried:

- freeing up 20GB of disk space
- downloading the box and manually untarring it
- using older versions of this vagrant box from months ago

but I am still unable to get past this error. Help?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [known widespread issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1862700) with the Bionic images. The following is a workaround until it's fixed:

1. Download the box manually from [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/20200206/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box)
2. Run `vagrant box add --name ubuntu/bionic64 /path/to/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box`
3. Try `vagrant up` again

Answer (score 0):

I've been having that issue for a while now. I would just go with the hashicorp box for Ubuntu 18 (bionic64)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  
  # Ubuntu 18 (bionic64) from Hashicorp
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
end
```